# wlanAPI on Windows XP SP3

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows-xp, wlanapi

My WPF application is using ManagedWifi to manually control the wifi adapter to connect to a specified network. However, when I run the application on Windows XP, I keep getting Win32Exception: The request is not supported (Native Error code 50).

The system that I was testing used Windows XP SP3, and I'm pretty sure that Windows XP SP3 supports NativeWifi:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx

This is the profile I'm using for the connection:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>Louis_flucard</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>4C6F7569735F666C7563617264</hex>
            <name>Louis_flucard</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>IBSS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>open</authentication>
                <encryption>none</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

And this is the code section that I used to connect to the wireless network:

```
//profileXml is basically the Xml file above
wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: add tag c++. This should be relevant since C/C++ can also work with Native Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the WlanConnect call isn't supported on XP. See the list of supported APIs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204766(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: You are right. Anyway as for my problem I have already had to disable support for XP, so there is no real solution yet..